# Как определить когда фиксировать указатель?

Tags: c#, .net

Если указатель получен на обычный массив - понятно, нужно фиксировать, даже в примерах на msdn есть такое. А если указатель получен от IntPtr или сам IntPtr - нужно ли фиксировать? Как понять когда нужно фиксировать, а когда не нужно?

---

Выделяем неуправляемую память:

```
    internal unsafe class Memory
    {
        // Heap API flags
        private const uint HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY = 0x00000008;

        // Heap API functions
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetProcessHeap();
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern int HeapSize(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr HeapAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwBytes);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern IntPtr HeapReAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpMem, UIntPtr dwBytes);
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool HeapFree(IntPtr hHeap, uint flags, IntPtr lpMem);

        // Handle for the process heap. This handle is used in all calls to the
        // HeapXXX APIs in the methods below.
        private static IntPtr ph = GetProcessHeap();

        // Private instance constructor to prevent instantiation.
        private Memory()
        {
        }

        // Allocates a memory block of the given size. The allocated memory is
        // automatically initialized to zero.
        public static IntPtr Alloc(int size)
        {
            IntPtr result = HeapAlloc(ph, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, new UIntPtr((uint)size));
            if (result == null) throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            return result;
        }

        // Frees a memory block.
        public static void Free(IntPtr block)
        {
            if (!HeapFree(ph, 0, block)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        // Re-allocates a memory block. If the reallocation request is for a
        // larger size, the additional region of memory is automatically
        // initialized to zero.
        public static IntPtr ReAlloc(IntPtr block, int size)
        {
            IntPtr result = HeapReAlloc(ph, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, block, new UIntPtr((uint)size));
            if (result == null) throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            return result;
        }

        // Returns the size of a memory block.
        public static int SizeOf(IntPtr block)
        {
            int result = HeapSize(ph, 0, block);
            if (result == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Объявляем IntPtr как поле класса:

```
    class Program
    {
        static IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            buffer = Memory.Alloc(100);
            byte* ptr = (byte*)buffer.ToPointer();

            // Не снесет ли сборщик мусора указатель ptr в произвольном месте?

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фиксировать нужно управляемые объекты  при передаче в нативный код или при использовании указателей внутри unsafe кода, для того, что бы при сборке мусора, указатель не подвергся дефрагментации. 
Обычно IntPtr в управляемом коде это указатель на на память из натива, котрый в отличие от .Net сборке мусора и дефрагментации не подвергается.

Фиксируются только управляемые объекты. IntPtr к таковым не относится, так как вообще структура

То есть если ты получил IntPtr то можешь получить данные используя методы Marshal

```
var str= Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(Элемент));
```

Так же можно передать ссылку или скопировать данные например

```
var ИсточникPrt = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(Источник);
                var СообщениеPrt = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(Сообщение);
                var ДанныеPrt = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(Данные);
                ВнешнееСобытие1С(ИсточникPrt, СообщениеPrt, ДанныеPrt);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ИсточникPrt);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(СообщениеPrt);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ДанныеPrt);
```

Где ВнешнееСобытие1С это делегат на нативную функцию полученную через

```
// Делегат для выделения памяти на стороне неуправляемого кода
        internal static ВыделитьПамятьDelegate ВыделитьПямять;
        //Делегат для сообщения об ошибке в неуправляемый код
        internal static ИнформацияОбОшибкеDelegate ИнформацияОбОшибке;
        internal static ВнешнееСобытие1СDelegate ВнешнееСобытие1С;

        internal static string CoreClrDir, NetObjectToNativeDir;
        //Вызвается из натива. Устанавливаем нужные делегаты
        public static void SetDelegate(IntPtr ДляВыделенияПамяти, IntPtr ДляВызоваОшибки, IntPtr ДляВызоваВнешнегоСобытия)
        {
            ВыделитьПямять = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ВыделитьПамятьDelegate>(ДляВыделенияПамяти);
            ИнформацияОбОшибке = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ИнформацияОбОшибкеDelegate>(ДляВызоваОшибки);
            ВнешнееСобытие1С = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ВнешнееСобытие1СDelegate>(ДляВызоваВнешнегоСобытия);
        }
```

Ну и смотри  GCHandle.Alloc GCHandle.Free

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.free(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Т.е., фиксировать нужно только управляемые объекты, те же массивы байт - если с них берем указатель? Та же аллоцированная неуправляемая память, обернутая в intPtr - затронута сборщиком не будет, даже если получаем указатель от IntPtr?

Comment: Господи, как же вырвиглазно смотрится кириллица в названиях переменных. 5 минут, дополню вопрос примером.

Comment: Да. Посмотри  примеры. В нативе ссылка фиксирована в куче. Там нет дефрагментации.

Comment: Это с непривычки. Мне так очень удобно. Я ведь 1С ник

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример кода. Судя по вашему ответу ничего страшного с ptr в методе Main не должно случиться.

Comment: Да ничего страшного не произойдет. Память выделена в нативной куче и она дефрагментации не подвергается. IntPtr и сделан для неизменяемых указателей https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Я не про IntPtr, я про полученный от него указатель byte* ptr. Не снесет ли GC его?

Comment: Подведя итоги можно сказать что фиксировать нужно только указатели на управляемые объекты, которые используются внутри управляемого кода или передаются в нативный код. Указатели на память, выделенную в нативном коде не подвержены сборке мусора и их можно использовать не фиксируя.

Comment: Добавить внутри unsafe кода

Comment: А не unsafe код просто напросто не даст использовать указатели.