# Маршаллинг структуры с указателями на функции в C#

Tags: c#, c

В dll имеется структура, поля которой - callback-и:

```
typedef struct callbacks
{
    char(*callback1)(params);
    void(*callback2)(void);
    char(*callback3)(params);
} Callbacks;
```

Как все это представить на C#? На данный момент я думаю о `IntPtr`, но может быть я не прав?

Comment: Ну в шарпе делегаты для этого используют.

Comment: Если dll ваша - то советую обратить внимание на такую технологию, как [COM](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589886/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%B8-c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-com-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC/589887#589887).

Comment: Можно и через IntPtr используя Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c/585767#585767

Comment: Про взаимодействие манагед и унманагед можно посмотреть здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/304482/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы представить в управляемом виде указатель на функцию - нужно использовать делегат. Делегату также придется задать соглашение о вызове с помощью [`UnmanagedFunctionPointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute.aspx):

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate byte Callback1Type();
```

Comment: а функции разве строки возвращают а не один символ?

Comment: @Grundy Кстати да, у меня там возвращают byte, поскольку в юникоде один char занимает 2 байта, а в анси - 1. Или там можно и char поставить?

Comment: @Grundy да, я слепой. Конечно же один символ.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а просто Action или Func можно использовать? или нужно только делегаты, чтобы конкретный атрибут был?

Comment: @Grundy просто Action или Func будут маршалиться как clrcall