# Как подружить C++ и C# через COM наиболее простым способом?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, com

Все рецепты использования COM включают в себя создание библиотеки типов, ее регистрацию в реестре, регистрацию в реестре сервера...

В DLL-ке при этом надо создавать фабрику объектов.

Если есть исполнимый файл на C# и DLL на C++ - можно ли обойтись безо всех этих шагов и *просто загрузить dll-ку*?

Comment: Что же вас вынудило задать вопрос и сию же секунду на него ответить?

Comment: @nick_n_a тот факт, что информация на эту тему в инете очень тяжело ищется и наполнена вредными советами и мифами.

Comment: Можно и без COM https://habrahabr.ru/post/304482/

Comment: @Serginio отличный пример вредного совета... Посмотрите на объем кода в статье.

Comment: @pavel-mayorov Ну зато там пример взаимодействия манагед кода с унманагед

Comment: @Serginio Но с COM-то проще! Как минимум, не требуется никаких AutoWrap, менеджеров памяти и вариантов!

Comment: Угу в линукс. Там можно и без AutoWrap вызывать статические методы. AutoWrap просто дает работать объектам через рефлексию. А для COM нужно либо самому обертку делать либо через Ireflect http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-c-%d0%b2-1%d0%a1/527802#527802

Comment: Кстати зная ClassID можно загружать без регистрации http://pastebin.com/embed/8EJHyJS0

Comment: @Serginio можно, но зачем вообще нужен ClassID? Кстати, у вас ссылка битая.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ICallback : IUnknown это, что?  Это просто примитивный пример. А вот когда нужны классы с сотнями методами и классами

Comment: @Serginio ...то никаких проблем не возникает.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот загрузка COM без регистрации http://pastebin.com/8EJHyJS0

Comment: @Serginio зачем нужен свой IDispatch?! Только ради GUID-константы? :)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov можно и без IDispatch нужен ClassID для получения  фабрики а из нее нужный интерфейс, который не обязательно IDispatch. Это к тому, что не обязательно регистрировать библиотеку.

Comment: Можно использовать С++/CLI http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/#The_C_library  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2012/11/14/ccli-and-mixed-mode-programming/

Comment: Возможно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597717/17974 такой пример подключения библиотеки вам понравится.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, можно. Технология COM не требует для своего использования какой бы то ни было регистрации в реестре!

Все перечисленные в вопросе шаги нужны для уменьшения связности модулей. Если вам эти шаги не подходят, не нужны или вам просто лень их делать - их можно пропустить.

Вот работающий **минимальный** пример.

### C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface ICallback
{
    void execute();
}

class Program : ICallback
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetCallbacks(new Program());
    }

    [DllImport("mylib", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern void SetCallbacks(ICallback callback);

    void ICallback.execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

### С++

```cpp
#include "windows.h"

interface ICallback : IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall execute() = 0;
};


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetCallbacks(ICallback *cb) {
    cb->execute();
}
```

---

В примере выше интерфейсы на двух языках были составлены независимо. В принципе, это является двойной работой - поэтому имеет смысл составить интерфейс только 1 раз, после чего его импортировать.

Если интерфейс составляется в C++-проекте на языке IDL - то достаточно потом подключить библиотеку типов в C#-проект как зависимость. Регистрировать ее при этом не обязательно!

Если интерфейс составляется в C#-проекте, то надо обязательно поставить ему кроме перечисленных выше атрибут [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) и сделать его публичным. После этого можно вытащить библиотеку типов через tlbexp и подключить в C++-проект. Регистрировать библиотеку типов в реестре, опять-таки, не требуется.

Comment: Кстати вот еще пример вызов объектного метода https://github.com/Marqin/simpleCoreCLRHost/blob/master/Managed.cs

Comment: @Serginio Один метод так вызвать можно. Но десяток проще все же вызывать через интерфейс. В любом случае, вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Надо будет попробовать для .Net Core вызов виртуальных методов C++

Comment: Интересует вызов виртуальных методов С++ классов из манагед кода

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю про возможность взаимодействие С++ кода с .Net Core.
В .Net Core есть возможность вызвать статические .Net методы через использование coreclr.dll из натива. Посмотреть примеры и ссылки можно здесь  [Кроссплатформенное использование классов .Net из неуправляемого кода. Или аналог IDispatch на Linux](https://habrahabr.ru/post/304482/)

В итоге можно передавать нативные методы в управляемый код и обратно. Но меня заинтересовало использование объектов и виртуальные методы. Поэтому задал вопрос и получил ответ  [.Net Core Вызов виртуальных методов нативных объектов](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/6611240.1) 
  При этом на 1 вызов метода идет куча QueryInterface, AddRef и Release это нужно учитывать

Я приведу свой пример.

Опишем класс на С++

```
struct ICallback : IUnknown
{
public:




    // Унаследовано через IUnknown
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject) override;

    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override;

    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override;

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall execute(int value);

};

typedef void(STDMETHODCALLTYPE *ManagedRunCallback)(ICallback*);
```

реализация

```
 // {FFB46654-083E-486A-94B8-E28B5C01561D}
        static const GUID IID_ICallback =
        { 0xffb46654, 0x83e, 0x486a,{ 0x94, 0xb8, 0xe2, 0x8b, 0x5c, 0x1, 0x56, 0x1d } };




        HRESULT __stdcall ICallback::execute(int value)
        {

            wprintf_s(L"ICallback from.Net %d\n", value);
            return NOERROR;
        }

        HRESULT __stdcall ICallback::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)
        {


            if (!ppvObject)
                return E_INVALIDARG;

          if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
            {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
                return S_OK;
            }
            else if (riid == IID_ICallback)
            {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<ICallback*>(this);

                return S_OK;
            }

            *ppvObject = nullptr;

            return E_NOINTERFACE;

        }

    // Меня интересует только вызов виртуальных методов
  // без отслеживания подсчета ссылок
        ULONG __stdcall ICallback::AddRef(void)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        ULONG __stdcall ICallback::Release(void)
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

теперь описание на C#

```
 [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("FFB46654-083E-486A-94B8-E28B5C01561D")]
    public interface ICallback
    {
        void execute(int value);
    }
```

и статический метод

```
 public static void CallInterface(IntPtr cb)
        {

            var cb2 = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(cb)  as ICallback;

            cb2?.execute(555);

        }
```

теперь я могу вызвать .Net метод из С++

```
ManagedRunCallback  pRunCallback;
if (!CreateDelegate(domainId, L"CallInterface", (INT_PTR*)&pRunCallback)) return false;

        ICallback* cb = new ICallback();
        pRunCallback(cb);
```

Comment: Зачем дублировать унаследованные методы в интерфейсе?

Comment: Они обозначены как абстрактные. И это не интерфейс это класс. И обозначены они как override

Comment: Э... А почему класс начинается с префикса `I`? :)

Comment: Это потому, что я  еще тот программист на С++.  Там как таковых интерфейсов то нет. Есть классы (структуры) с абстрактными методами

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще один вариант с использованием VMT в .Net Core.
Вызов интерфейса очень дорогое удовольствие. С для приведение к нужному интерфейсу и подсчета ссылок идет куча вызовов QueryInterface Addref,Release [Вызов методов интерфейса из C#](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/6611240.1)

Определим С++ класс

```
struct TestThisCall {
    public:
        virtual int  execute(int value1, int value2);

    };

    typedef void(STDMETHODCALLTYPE *ManagedRunCallback2)(TestThisCall*);
```

Создадим метод для получения метода в VMT

```
public static IntPtr ПолучитьАдресВиртуальногоМетода(IntPtr Объект, int ИндексВТаблицеВиртуальныхМетодов )
        {
            int размерIntPtr = Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>();

            // Первым полем объекта идет ссылка на VMT
            // Прочитаем её
            var АдресVMT = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(Объект);
            //  получим адрес ссылки на  метод по смещению в VMT
            var АдресМетодаVMT = АдресVMT + ИндексВТаблицеВиртуальныхМетодов * размерIntPtr;
            var АдресМетода = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(АдресМетодаVMT);

            return АдресМетода;
        }
```

Теперь определим описание делегата

```
 [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
            internal delegate int ВиртуальныйМетодОбъекта2Delegate(IntPtr self, int Число1, int Число2);
```

И статический метод который будем вызывать из натива

```
public static void CallTestThisCall(IntPtr ttc)
        {

            // Метод execute идет первым в VMT
            // Передаем индекс 0
            var АдресМетода = ПолучитьАдресВиртуальногоМетода(ttc, 0);
            // Получим делегат по дресу
            var execute = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ВиртуальныйМетодОбъекта2Delegate>(АдресМетода);

            // И вызовем метод
          var res=  execute(ttc, ttc.ToInt32(), 777);
          execute(ttc, ttc.ToInt32(), res);
        }
```

Теперь вызовем этот метод из C++

```
ManagedRunCallback2 pRunCallback2;
    if (!CreateDelegate(domainId, L"CallTestThisCall", (INT_PTR*)&pRunCallback2)) return false;

    TestThisCall* ttc = new TestThisCall();
    pRunCallback2(ttc);
```

Ну и чудесный пример на RSDN [.Net Core Вызов виртуальных методов нативных объектов](http://rsdn.org/forum/dotnet/6614203.1)

Comment: С чего бы оно дорогое-то, удовольствие?..

Comment: Я же ссылку привел. Там куча QueryInterface, Addref, Release идет. В моих задачах нужно вызвать один два метода без подсчета ссылок итд